# Format of flv-videos for a RTMP-implementation

Tags: flash, flv, rtmp

I'm implementing the RTMP-protocol for my bachelor thesis. I got through the handshake and application connect process and received the play-command from my client which is actually a jw player.
But I now stuck with the audio and video-messages. I can't find something about the exactly built-up of these messages neither in the specification nor somewhere else. Can someone help me how these messages have to look like?
For testing i got a simple flash screen video from this website: http://klaus.geekserver.net/libflv/ (screen.flv)
What should i do with the metadata and header of the flv-file? Can I send the whole tag and audio-/video-data from my file in the RTMP-audio- and video-messages?

Answer (score 0):

Ok if someone is interested in the answer. After a lot of watching bytes and code of flazr i found out someting. It doesn't work yet but i can say that there is a data message (message type 0x12), which has the original metadata of a flv-file in its payload. After this the audio- and videomessages are send, which contain the tag and body of a flv-file.